# System.AccessViolationException in UiAutomationCore.dll

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, ui-automation, uia

We have a testing automation tool which uses UI Automation API a lot. It occurs that in newest versions of Windows (like Windows 10 21H2, Windows 11) api throws exception `System.AccessViolationException` while invoking one of the methods of AutomationElement class.
Here is our code:

```
AutomationElement uiaElement;
....            
var cr = new CacheRequest
{
    AutomationElementMode = AutomationElementMode.None,
    TreeScope = TreeScope.Element,
    TreeFilter = Automation.RawViewCondition
};
cr.Add(InvokePattern.Pattern);
cr.Add(TogglePattern.Pattern);
cr.Add(RangeValuePattern.Pattern);
cr.Add(ValuePattern.Pattern);
cr.Add(ItemContainerPattern.Pattern);
cr.Add(VirtualizedItemPattern.Pattern);

var cachedElement = uiaElement.GetUpdatedCache(capabilitiesCacheRequest);
```

And stack trace:
[image]

Method `GetUpdatedCache` comes from `AutomationElement`(`UIAutomationClient.dll`) and invokes method from `UIAutomationCore.dll` called `RawUiaHPatternObjectFromVariant` - this method throws exception and I am not sure how to proceed given that everything works fine on earlier versions of Windows.

For now we just tried handling this exception - of course it is not acceptable in a long run.

One thing to mention is that both newever versions of Windows on which we tested this are in preview/beta state. Is this possible that certain API are "disabled" in such versions (of course they maybe also be broken), does anyone has experience with such situations? I am asking about both - solving System.AccessViolationException in general and not properly working API in beta/preview releases.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Ehssan actually not entirely. We removed the method invocation which caused issues and we no longer use "cachedElement". It was needed before for calling "TryGetCachedPatter" in code. Now, we use "TryGetCurrentPattern" on "uiaElement". However, this is still in testing stage...

Answer (score 1):

You might need to turn off completely Windows [UAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/winenv-uac) and Defender/[SmartScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/microsoft-defender-smartscreen/microsoft-defender-smartscreen-available-settings), and add [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-security-overview) to exe to run tests under elevated account.