# Access Violation Exception in UISpy / Inspect when checking application controls in Win11 OS

Tags: windows-11, ui-spy

When inspecting controls of a desktop application using UISpy with a Windows 11 OS it is throwing an exception in the Output pane for each control

```
Time Stamp : 28/01/2022 9:38 AM
Element : "combo box" "Payment To"
Name : AccessViolationException
Message : Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Stack Trace :    at MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.RawUiaHPatternObjectFromVariant(Object& var, SafePatternHandle& hnode)
   at MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.UiaCacheResponse.ConvertFromComTypesToClrTypes(Object[,] data, UiaCacheRequest request)
   at MS.Internal.Automation.UiaCoreApi.UiaGetUpdatedCache(SafeNodeHandle hnode, UiaCacheRequest request, NormalizeState normalize, Condition customCondition)
   at System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement.GetUpdatedCache(CacheRequest request)
   at UISpy.Base.Node.GetUpdatedCache(CacheRequest cacheRequest)
```

Its happening on nearly all controls in the application so the Control Properties show as "{null}"

When I use Windows 10 OS I do not get this issue.

Any ideas why this may occur in Win11?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68457721/system-accessviolationexception-in-uiautomationcore-dll

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/715419/win32-application-exe-closes-with-access-violation.html